# Why isn't this referring to window when called in setTimeout

Tags: javascript

If there is no binding of functions to instances in javascript how does `getName()` return `john`

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "john";
    this.getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    };
}

var me = new Person();
setTimeout(function(){alert(me.getName())}, 3000);
```

I though `this` would refer to the window at the point of call from `setTimeout`.

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qZeXG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that the anonymous function executed by `setTimeout` closes over the `me` variable, which is a `Person` instance. Because of closure, you can still reference `me` when that function is later called.

When you invoke `me.getName()` you're invoking a method on the `Person` instance, which sets the value of `this` to `me` inside that function. This is just a normal method invocation.

Note that in the following code:

```
var me = new Person();
setTimeout(function() {
    alert(this);
    alert(me.getName());
}, 3000);
```

...the value of `this` in the first `alert` *is* the `window` object. It's the ordinary method invocation that is changing the value.

Consider this final example:

```
var me = new Person();
var getName = me.getName;
setTimeout(function(){ alert(getName()) }, 3000);
```

In this case the function also closes over a reference to `getName`, but the function that that variable points to is invoked without any information about the `Person` instance it came from. Therefore, the value of `this` inside `getName` *will* be the `window` object.

Conclusion? This statement:

> ...there is no binding of functions to instances in javascript...

...is a false assumption.

Comment: Is it really a wrong assumption, it seems that the fact it needs the anonymous function to close over means that the important thing is the binding of the function to the context, i.e closure, as if you do `setTimeout(me.getName(), 3000);` there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

`this` will be the Person instance, because you called `getName` on the `me` object.

If you just called `getName` directly and not as a property of `me`, `this` would refer to the window.

For example:

```
var getName = me.getName;
alert (getName ())
```

or

```
alert (me.getName.call (this))
```